# Pass props React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to pass props through React Router to LawsList Component. So I come up with this code:

On main.js :

```
const lawlistcomponent = props => {
  console.log("test");
  return <LawsList {...props} />;
};

const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute render={lawlistcomponent} />
      <Route path="laws/:lawId" component={LawsMain} />
      <Route path="votes/:lawId" component={VotesMain} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

And on LawsList component :

```
 export default createContainer(props => {
  console.log(this.props.voted);
  Meteor.subscribe("laws", props.voted);
  return { laws: Laws.find({}).fetch() };
}, LawsList);
```

It does not return the component at all. I have no error message that could guide either !

Any hint ?

Comment: You are close with this, instead of creating lawlistcomponent just inline that into the render prop of your IndexRoute. Similar to the ‘answer’ below but with render instead of component. P.S. I see this question asked almost daily.

Comment: Do you mean  <IndexRoute render={(props)=> <LawsList {...props} /> ? Sorry very newbie!

Comment: Yes but that is with router v4. I also would do () => instead of (props) =>

Answer (score 4):

Your local `lawlistcomponent` component is not receiving any props in the way it was passed to the route. Anyway, I'd recommend you to use the `render` inline function to render the component to the route (supposing that you are using the React Router V4). Like this:

```js
<Route
  exact
  path='/'
  render={(props) => <LawsList {...props} anotherProp={value} />}
/>
```

As described in the React [router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func):

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above. Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop receives all the same route props as the component render prop.

Thanks [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9407501/jens) for your suggestion.

Comment: Nice work, thanks for updating. Although the route props are passed to it, it may be necessary to remove the props argument in order to use the one in the parent scope.

Comment: Thank you , only I am using React Router v3. Does that change the syntax ?

Comment: @Sonia for React Router V3 you could follow this example from the official repository -> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/examples/passing-props-to-children/app.js

Comment: so you mean creating a const that will pass the props ? Sorry , i am very new at this, could you please guide me a little bit on this ?

Comment: @Sonia, before we dig in on this (what I think will be a bit difficult to do here), depending on the size of the application you are working on, it may be a good idea to update React Router to the latest version, and refactor the code to work with it. It may be a good solution, as you could rely in the oficial React Router docs for version 4 to help you with thtat.

Comment: Yes upgrade to router 4. It is a pretty important update and the longer you wait to update the harder it will be in the future.